# Атрибут href в HTML

Tags: html5

Как сделать несколько ссылок на одну фразу/слово?

То есть жму на слово а откроет одновременно 2 или больше вкладок

Что-то типа

```
<a href='...' href='...'>
```

Answer (score 3):

Никак. Можно навесить обработчик со всякими window.open, либо программные клики по фиктивным ссылкам, но все современные браузеры такие фокусы не позволят, если только пользователь сам не разрешил всплывающие окна.

Comment: а знаеш как реализовать ето с помощю джаваскрипта?

Comment: Ещё раз. Если пользователь явно в браузере не разрешит popup-окна (а по умолчанию они запрещены), то работать не будет.

Comment: так мне не сразу, мне если ползователь кликнул на что-то
я только-что прочел что если по клику то можно

Comment: Сомнительно. Даже если одно можно (а для этого и без скриптов есть `target=_blank`), то много браузер должен порезать... Ладно, а в чём вообще-то проблема?

Comment: делаю сайт(задание с универа) а нас 5 в команде и хочу добавить кнопку 'about us'

Comment: Так не делают...

Comment: а как адекватно сделать?

Comment: Как у всех. Одну страницу с перечислением и описанием. На ней разместить 5 дополнительных ссылок. Ты где видел сайты, чтобы по клику на about us открывались сайты всех разработчиков? o_O

Comment: кстате да, про ето я не подумал)

Comment: @lalalala Этот ответ является правильным и полным, рекомендую принять его (галка слева от поста под кнопками голосования).